# How to add my own HTML and Javascript codes to Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, javascript, css, custom, html

This must be a basic question but I cant find an answer to use. I did some custom functions with Javascript and a design (css/html) and now I want to include them in a Magento 1 project, how can I achieve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create this file - `app/design/frontend/yourWebsite/yourStore/layout/local.xml`

Populate it with the below code changing the values to match your files.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/your-js-file.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/your-css-file.css</name></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="your.template" template="path/to/your/template.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```